# Why type of pure is a -> f a, not (a -> b) -> f (a -> b) on Applicative?

Tags: haskell, applicative

Pure is used to transform normal function into function in `Applicative` container. With this, any multi-parameter operations become can be used on `Applicative`. In this context, pure is not desired to be `a -> f a` type, it is just desired to be `(a -> b) -> f (a -> b)` type. But type of `pure` is `a -> f a`. Why should normal values can be transformed into `Applicative`? Is there more purpose for use `pure` more than transforming functions?

Comment: `(a -> b) -> f (a -> b)` **is** a possible instantiation of `pure`'s type. And no, `pure` is not generally “used to transform normal function into function in `Applicative` container”, that sounds rather like you're describing `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. I'd rather say `pure` is used to transform normal _values_ into values in an `Applicative` context. It so happens that functions are values as well, but that's a special case.

Comment: What you are probably thinking about is the `pure f` in `fmap f fx = pure f <*> fx`, but the `fx`, where would it come from? `pure x`, that's where, for one.

Answer (score 6):

I don't find the `Applicative` interface of applying lifted functions (namely, `(<*>)`) a good intuition. Functions are more complicated to conceptualize for various reasons.

I prefer thinking of `Applicative` as lifting an *n*-ary function

```hs
liftA0 :: Applicative f => (a)                -> (f a)
liftA  :: Functor     f => (a -> b)           -> (f a -> f b)
liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c)      -> (f a -> f b -> f c)
liftA3 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c -> d) -> (f a -> f b -> f c -> f d)
```

where `liftA0 = pure` and `liftA` already exists as `fmap` defined in terms of `Applicative`.

The thing is that 0-ary and 1-ary liftings

```
liftA0 @f @a    :: Applicative f => a -> f a
liftA  @f @a @b :: Applicative f => (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
```

can both take an `a -> b` function if we instantiate `liftA0 = pure` at a function type:

```
liftA0 @f @(a->b) :: Applicative f => (a -> b) -> f (a->b)
liftA  @f @a @b   :: Applicative f => (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
```

So `pure @f @(a->b)` already has that type.

And `pure` has plenty of purposes, theoretical which turn out to be practical in Haskell, it is the unit if `Applicative` is viewed as a `Monoid` in the category of natural transformations, with ([Notions of Computation as Monoids](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.4823.pdf)) with [`Day`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.2.3/docs/Data-Functor-Day.html)

```
type Mempty :: Type -> Type
type Mempty = Identity

type Mappend :: (Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type)
type Mappend = Day

mempty :: Applicative f => Mempty ~> f
mempty (Identity a) = pure a

mappend :: Mappend f f ~> f
mappend (LiftA2 (·) as bs) = liftA2 (·) as bs
```

I just released a library that works with `Applicative` homomorphisms, that are polymorphic functions that respect the applicative structure. It defines a type class for such structures

```hs
type  Idiom :: k -> (Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type) -> Constraint
class (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Idiom tag f g where
  idiom :: f ~> g
```

where `pure` is the [initial applicative morphism](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/idiomatic-0.1.1.0/docs/Generic-Applicative-Idiom.html#t:Initial).

```hs
-- https://chrisdone.com/posts/haskell-constraint-trick/
instance (Identity ~ id, Applicative f) => Idiom Initial id f where
  idiom :: Identity ~> f
  idiom (Identity a) = pure a
```

`pure` is then frequently used, as a unit for a computation. It is the driving force in `Traversable` one of the success stories of Haskell

```hs
instance Traversable [] where
  traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> ([a] -> f [b])
  traverse f []     = pure []
  traverse f (x:xs) = ...
```

we require `pure` because our only argument that produces an `Applicative`-action is `f x` but with an empty list we don't have an `x :: a` to feed it. Thus, we need 0-ary lifting.

Answer (score 5):

You can define `pure :: a -> f a` in terms of `lift :: (a -> b) -> f (a -> b)` and `<*>`:

```
pure x = lift (const x) <*> lift (const ())
```

So it's equivalent either way, and usually simpler to write `pure`.

(This is in addition to Iceland_jack's excellent summary of the design reasons it should be this way.)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's worth approaching questions from the opposite direction. What would you gain if the type of `pure` was `(a -> b) -> f (a -> b)`?

As someone calling `pure`, that's strictly a downgrade. As mentioned, `(a -> b) -> f (a -> b)` is an instantiation of the current type of `pure` already. So on the calling side, you only lose options.

The implementation side is the dual here, though. The more concrete a type is, the more options an implementation has. Requiring the argument to be a function means the implementation can take advantage of that to do function-specific things. Like... calling it. That's the only special thing you get to do with functions in Haskell. So to call it, you just need to provide it with a value of some type `a` that the caller of `pure` gets to choose. You can get one of those by.. uh.. you can't get one of those. The only option is using `undefined` or some other bottom value that has a universally-quantified type. What are you going to do? `pure f = let x = f undefined in ...`? How can that be helpful for implementing pure?

To return to the initial question, then: what would you gain if the type of `pure` was `(a -> b) -> f (a -> b)`? As a caller, it's strictly less useful. As an implementer, it provides additional power, but that additional power doesn't help you do anything useful. Where are the upsides to a more concrete type?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is more purpose for `pure` than transforming functions. It is very common for `do` blocks to end with a call to `pure`. It's also handy for giving fallback values by combining its use with `<|>`.

Also, it meshes well with the underlying category theory; but I don't really consider that a motivating reason. Rather it's first useful and then discovered to coincide with a previously-known category theory concept. (Actually, historically I think it went "define something useful; realize it's the concept of monad; discover the related concept of applicative functors; realize they're useful. So it is in fact a mix of "useful first" and "theory first". But I would never defend its existence *because* it's there in theory -- only get excited that the theory was insightful.)